# Looping through JSON data and combining the objects into a single array

Tags: ajax, json, loops

I am getting JSON data from an API and need to loop throughout the data to get latitude and longitudes coordinates. Then take those coordinates and pass them into a map by storing them in an array.

here is what I have so far

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'APIUrl',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(locations) {

      console.log(locations);
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.results.length; i++) {
        var latitude = locations.results[i].geocode.lat;
        var longitude = locations.results[i].geocode.long;
        var name = locations.results[i].name;
        var coordinates = [{name: name, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, radius: 2}];
            bombMap.bubbles(coordinates, {
         popupTemplate: function (geo, data) { 
          return ['<div class="hoverinfo">' +  data.name, '</div>'].join('');
         }
          }); 
      }; 
    },
});
```

When I console.log(coordinates); it outputs all the correct data as individual arrays, but now I need to combine it all into a single array.

I have tried $.merge and $.extend with no luck.

Example of the JSON output:

```
Object {results: Array[310], count: 310}
count: 310
results: Array[310]
[0 … 99]
0: Object
address: Object
bucket: "fair"
clientRefId: "53ecdf1a2000008307b96dbf"
description: ""
email: ""
errors: Array[4]
geocode: Object
accuracy: "Medium"
lat: 38.95376968383789
long: -77.44419860839844
__proto__: Object
1: Object
```

Need to have the name and geocode data stored into a variable like so

```
var = [{
  name:
  latitude:
  longitude: },{
  name:
  latitude:
  longitude: }
];
```

Comment: could you provide an example of the result data you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out, and was stupid to not notice it sooner.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'APIUrl',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(locations) {
        var locals = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.results.length; i++) {
        var latitude = locations.results[i].geocode.lat;
        var longitude = locations.results[i].geocode.long;
        var name = locations.results[i].name;
        var coordinates = {name: name, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, radius: 2};
        locals.push(coordinates); 
      }; 
      bombMap.bubbles(locals, {
       popupTemplate: function (geo, data) { 
        return ['<div class="hoverinfo">' +  data.name, '</div>'].join('');
       }
      });
    },
});
```

Need to declare an empty array outside of the for loop then use .push to fill it with the coordinates. Should have spoted that much sooner

Answer (score 0):

To get one big array:

```
concatenatedCoordinates = coordinates.reduce(function(a, b){return a.concat(b);});
```

I hope I understood your question right.

Comment: Thanks but that gives the same output as if I remove [ ] from the coordinates variable. it doesn't combine the objects into an array